# How exactly does inclusion in postgresql ranges work?

Tags: postgresql

I am reading the documentation for ranges [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/rangetypes.html) and there it states:

```
-- includes only the single point 4
SELECT '[4,4]'::int4range;
```

Okay but when I execute this, I get

```
SELECT '[4,4]'::int4range;
 int4range
-----------
 [4,5)
(1 row)
```

Why is `5` included in the result?

Also getting the upper value, it gives

```
SELECT upper('[4,4]'::int4range);
 upper
-------
     5
(1 row)
```

Then the lower bound, it gives

```
SELECT lower('[4,4]'::int4range);
 lower
-------
     4
(1 row)
```

So obviously this does not include a single point? This includes 4 and 5. That is not a single value.

Also I thought when I create a range with `[]` I am saying lower and upper bound should be inclusive in the range, so why does running `SELECT '[4,4]'::int4range;` gives `[4,5)` where the range is enclosed in `[)` instead of `[]` that I was expecting.

I also tried with dataranges. I did

```
SELECT generate_series(lower('[2023-10-18,2023-10-18]'::daterange), upper('[2023-10-18,2023-10-18]'::daterange), interval '1 day')::date AS individual_date;
 individual_date
-----------------
 2023-10-18
 2023-10-19
```

I was expecting only `2023-10-18`. Why is there two entries in the result?

It seems I really don't understand how the ranges are supposed to work, as results conflicts with my expectations.

Comment: this is not how a range is defined, it is a conversion from an array see https://dbfiddle.uk/FNyUMgFX

Comment: i sincerely do not get why you cannot use '[]' but you can use `[)` to define a range, which will then behave as an inclusive [] range

Comment: Also why would you say that is not the way to create a range, when the documentation, where i picked the example was creating a range with []?

Comment: an range is not an array, so the conversion is necessary

Comment: Read the docs [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) it goes through how range types are defined/built and their usage step by step. It may take a couple of reads, but the information you seek is all there.

Comment: @nbk, that is how a range can be defined. The issue is the output may not meet expectations, unless you have read what `[` and `)` mean for the different types of ranges.

Answer (score 3):

an angle bracket (`[`) means that that end of the interval is included, while a parenthesis (`(`) means that the end is excluded.

So `'[4,4]'::int4range` is a range that consists only of the number 4 (both ends are included), and `'[4,5)'::int4range` *also* consists only of the number 4 (the upper end 5 is excluded). PostgreSQL normalizes values range types so that the lower bound is included and the upper bound is excluded, whenever possible. This works (and confuses people) when the underlying data type is discrete, like `integer` or `date`. With a continuous data type, that normalization does not happen: you cannot rewrite `'[1,2]'::numrange` to an equivalent range with the upper end excluded.

In short: there is nothing to worry, everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into [8.17.7. Discrete Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE) in PostgreSQL documentation. It states:

> The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, [). (...)

When you define a range like `'[4,4]'::int4range` it is converted to canonical form of `[4,5)`. That is why the upper limit becomes 5.

If it was not the case then the same range defined using different textual representations would have different properties (limits).